# Google Analytics on non-public pages

Tags: google-analytics

Is good to place google analytics in pages like admistration, article edit page, ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why I use Google Analytics is to give important information to my clients about how their websites are being used. Because of that I wouldnt include the admin area of the website because it doesnt affect their sales or conversions.

By adding code into the admin zone you are inflating the total pageviews. If you really want to track this information then its not a disaster, you would just need to be sure to setup a profile which filters out these urls when making business decisions with your Analytics info.

Technically I think to use Google Analytics it is supposed to be on a free, public website but I guess having some of the pages locked isnt going to get your account closed.

Comment: Where does GA say that it's solely meant for free public pages? I don't think that's the case. For example, it's very common practice to put GA on login-protected pages. Even their example of how to use Custom Variables supposes that. There's a difference between tracking backend pages (which is uncommon but no win) and tracking nonfree login only pages (totally common).

Comment: you can use GA for any page you want.  But as retpHarry said... you have to consider how actionable putting tracking on those pages is.  Is gaining insight into those pages going to somehow allow your client to make some kind of business decision? Fine tune some sales/conversion funnel? The whole point of web analytics is to track activity on a website to see how to increase sales (both directly and indirectly). For instance, steps in a registration process or shopping cart sales process.

Comment: yes sorry I did double check the terms and it doesnt say anything like this, you can use it anywhere you want.  I think that what I was thinking of is the Google Maps API restrictions where you have to have free access to the site otherwise you have to use Maps Premier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it keeps stats on how often you or others use admin features. I also suggest that you use Google webmaster tools on them too.